# Create Observable from non-standard event (no EventArgs / EventHandler)

Tags: c#, .net, events, observable, system.reactive

I would like to create an Observable for an event defined as follows:

```
public event Func<Exception, Task> Closed;
```

The current code I have is this:

```
Observable.FromEvent<Func<Exception, Task>, Unit>(h => hub.Closed += h, h=> hub.Closed -= h);
```

It compiles OK, but it throws this runtime exception:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot bind to the target method because
>   its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of
>   the delegate type.'

I feel that I'm doing it wrong. I'm not used to create observables from events that don't follow the EventArgs pattern

EDIT: Just for clarification purposes, this is the complete code with how the classic event handling would look:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var hub = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("http://localhost:49791/hubs/status")
            .Build();

        hub.On<Status>("SendAction", status => Console.WriteLine($"Altitude: {status.Altitude:F} m"));
        await hub.StartAsync();

        hub.Closed += HubOnClosed;

        while (true)
        {
        }
    }

    private static Task HubOnClosed(Exception arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The connection to the hub has been closed");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of using your event with traditional event handling code? That'll make it easier to turn it in to an observable.

Comment: Thanks @Enigmativity. I'm consuming the Closed event from a 3rd party lib (SignalR Core). The event definition is here: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/2265acde7880fbced32355bcfe0bebe08a097360/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core/HubConnection.cs#L58

The code I'm trying is in this repo: https://github.com/SuperJMN/SignalRCoreSample. Feel free to clone it. It's really simple. Run the Server and the Client (concurrently) and you will get the exception.

Comment: @Enigmativity I've just added the code with the classic event handling. I hope it's enough. This is causing me headaches :) Big thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need the conversion overload. I shutter every time I look this thing up:

```
IObservable<TEventArgs> Observable.FromEvent<TDelegate, TEventArgs>(
    Func<Action<TEventArgs>, TDelegate> conversion, 
    Action<TDelegate> addHandler, 
    Action<TDelegate> removeHandler>
)
```

So in our case, `TEventArgs` is `Exception`, and `TDelegate` is `Func<Exception, Task>`, so you need to convert `Action<Exception>` to `Func<Exception, Task>>`, in other words: `Func<Action<Exception>, Func<Exception, Task>>`. I'm assuming that conversion looks like this: `a => e => {a(e); return Task.CompletedTask; }`.

System.Reactive needs this conversion function because it needs to subscribe to the event with a proper delegate, and somehow hook in your code/RX Plumbing code. In this case, `a(e)` is basically RX plumbing which then passes on the Exception to be handled later in the reactive pipeline.

Full code:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

        Program.Closed += Program.HubOnClosed;
        Observable.FromEvent<Func<Exception, Task>, Exception>(
            a => e => {a(e); return Task.CompletedTask; }, 
            h => Program.Closed += h, 
            h => Program.Closed -= h
        )
            .Subscribe(e =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Rx: The connection to the hub has been closed");
            });

        Program.Closed.Invoke(null);
        Program.Closed.Invoke(null);
    }

    private static Task HubOnClosed(Exception arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The connection to the hub has been closed");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public static event Func<Exception, Task> Closed;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does something like this do the trick?

```
class Program
{
    public event Func<Exception, Task> Closed;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        IObservable<Unit> closedObservable = Observable.Create<Unit>(
            observer =>
            {
                Func<Exception, Task> handler = ex =>
                {
                    observer.OnNext(Unit.Default);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };

                p.Closed += handler;

                return () => p.Closed -= handler;
            });
    }
}
```

`Observable.Create()` is a useful fallback for unusual cases like this.

As an aside, it's very strange to have an event with a non-void returning delegate, since the code that raises the event would only see the value of the last handler to run - unless it raises the event in some non-standard way. But, since it's library code, that's out of your hands!

Comment: Maybe this works, but I'd rather use `Observable.FromEvent` or `Observable.FromEventPattern` for that. I doubt the `Create` method is justified here. I hope you understand.

Comment: I see where you're coming from, but I suspect that fact the delegate is a `Func<>` not an `Action<>` is so unusual that Rx doesn't allow for it at all. Traditionally it would have been considered "bad," though I'm sure the SignalR devs have good reason for it ;-)

Comment: Ooops, so at first sight it looks like a bad design decision? Also, if I understand you well, the problem comes with the signature of the delegate being `Func<Exception, Task>` instead of an `Action<>`, right?

Comment: Exactly. I took a quick look at the SignalR code you referenced, and it looks as though they're `await`-ing the returned `Task` to do error logging, but, if I understand things correctly, they will end up doing that for only one of the event handlers.

Comment: From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks): "When the signature of the methods invoked by a delegate includes a return value, the delegate returns the return value of the last element in the invocation list."

Answer (score -2):

Try the following, not using the signature you want but something to try:

```
class Program
{
        public delegate void ClosedEventHandler(object sender, Func<Exception, Task> e);
        public ClosedEventHandler Closed { get; set; }    

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program hub = new Program();
            hub.Closed = hub.SomethingToDoWhenClosed;    
            Observable
                .FromEventPattern<ClosedEventHandler, Func<Exception, Task>>(
                    h => hub.Closed += h,
                    h => hub.Closed -= h)
                .Subscribe(x =>
                {
                    // this is hit
                });    
            hub.Closed(hub, e => null);
        }

        public void SomethingToDoWhenClosed(object sender, Func<Exception, Task> e)
        {
        }
}
```

Comment: `public delegate void ClosedEventHandler(object sender, Func e);` this doesn't compile

Comment: Sorry, the message was incorrectly formatted. I have edited it and now the code shows up OK. I'm going to try it.

Comment: With the link that doesn't work where is the return in main.

Comment: I forgot to return a Task, sorry, but adding a return Task.Complete, for instance, won't change anything. It won't compile. You could also await the Observable.FirstAsync. It won't compile, either 

Comment: The above code as shown runs for me on VS2017 and was able to debug into the subscribe. I think once you put the additional async code which is strange.

Comment: Oh, well... that's because you're not using the same code I use. Let me upload it somewhere

Comment: OK, here is the repository with the exact code. Run the Server, then run the Client and you will see the problem. The line with the observable is here: https://github.com/SuperJMN/SignalRCoreSample/blob/master/ConsoleApp1/Program.cs#L20